# How to create custom snippets in Visual Studio 2022 for Blazor files (*.razor)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, blazor, code-snippets

Is there a way that I can create my own custom snippets for Blazor files in Visual Studio 2022? I'm able to create custom snippets for C# using `<Code Language="CSharp">` in the .snippet file however, there is no such thing as `<Code Language="blazor">`. I can import using `CSharp` or `HTML` for code language but I'm unable to use it while coding on `*.razor` files. The shortcut shows up when I start typing but hitting tab does not bring the code snippet.

Is there any workaround or extension that can do this?